# Jquery condition doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must be doing some very basic mistake, because i cant get to result2, even though it checks the condition for it. it detects the counter and InpActive, but it only add up the counter once (but that should be enough to check for condition 2) nor perform the check for the test2 condition.

Edit: im presenting the full function. I want to make a mysqli query with each input, and i want to be able to add and take out each entry, preserving the query structure to be sent to the server. Its not working for some reason. In this post, im not adding the PHP part. Im only interested in making the jquery part work.

This is the jquery code:

```
var inpreco = ["", "", ""];
var altpreco = ["", "", ""];
var inprocess = ["", "", ""];
var altprocess = ["", "", ""];
var cpcounter8 = 0;
var cpcounter9 = 0;

$(".opcaopreco").click(function () {
    SuperFun(this, "#preco", inpreco, altpreco, "altpreco2", "cpvalor", 
"cpindex", "cpactivo", cpcounter9, "preco", "1 AND 5000");
});

$(".opcaopreco2").click(function () {
    SuperFun(this, "#process", inprocess, altprocess, "altprocess2", 
"cpvalor8", "cpindex8", "cpactivo8", cpcounter8, "process", "1 AND 11");
});

function SuperFun(element, input, inpArray, secArray, secArray2, inpValue, 
secIndex, inpActive, counter, msqlip, ending) {
 var inpValue = $("#" + element.id).val();
var secIndex = $("#" + element.id).data(secIndex);
var inpActive = $("#" + element.id).data(inpActive);   
if (counter==0){
    counter++;
    $("#" + element.id + "l").addClass("activa");
    $(element).data(inpActive, "primary");
    inpArray[0] = (inpValue);   
}else
if (inpActive=="") {
    counter++;
    $("#" + element.id + "l").addClass("activa");
    $(element).data(inpActive, "yes");
    inpArray[secIndex]=(" OR "+msqlip+" BETWEEN "+inpValue);
    secArray[secIndex]=(secIndex);      
}else
if (inpActive=="yes") {
    counter--;
    $("#" + element.id + "l").removeClass("activa");
    $(element).data(inpActive, "");
    inpArray[secIndex]="";
    secArray[secIndex] = "";
}else
if (inpActive=="primary" && counter!==1) {
    counter--;
    $("#" + element.id + "l").removeClass("activa");
    $(element).data(inpActive, "");
    secArray2 = secArray.filter(Boolean);
    inpArray[0]=$("#op" + secArray2[0]).val();
    inpArray[$("#op" + secArray2[0]).data(secIndex)]="";
    $("#op" + secArray2[0]).data(inpActive, "primary");
    secArray[$("#op" + secArray2[0]).data(secIndex)]="";    
} else
if (inpActive=="primary" && counter==1) {
    counter--;
    $("#" + element.id + "l").removeClass("activa");
    $(element).data(inpActive, "");
    inpArray[secIndex]="";
    inpArray[0]=ending;     
}
$(input).val(inpArray[0]+inpArray[1]+inpArray[2]);        
};
```

This is the html code:

```
<input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='1 AND 5000'><br><br>
    <input id="process" type="text" name="process" value='1 AND 11'><br><br>

    <div id="op1l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op1" class="opcaopreco" value="201 AND 400" data-cpindex="1" data-cpactivo="">
        <label for="op1"></label>
        <span class="itext">€201 - €400</span>
    </div>

    <div id="op2l" class="input">   
        <input type="checkbox" id="op2" class="opcaopreco" value='401 AND 600' data-cpindex="2" data-cpactivo="">
        <label for="op2"></label>
        <span class="itext">€401 - €600</span>
    </div>

    <div id="op3l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op3" class="opcaopreco" value='601 AND 800' data-cpindex="3" data-cpactivo="">
        <label for="op3"></label>
        <span class="itext">€601 - €800</span>
    </div>  

    <div id="op4l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op4" class="opcaopreco2" value="1 AND 1" data-cpindex8="1" data-cpactivo8="">
        <label for="op4"></label>
        <span class="itext">1 AND 1</span>
    </div>

    <div id="op5l" class="input">   
        <input type="checkbox" id="op5" class="opcaopreco2" value='2 AND 2' data-cpindex8="2" data-cpactivo8="">
        <label for="op5"></label>
        <span class="itext">2 AND 2</span>
    </div>

    <div id="op6l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op6" class="opcaopreco2" value='3 AND 3' data-cpindex8="3" data-cpactivo8="">
        <label for="op6"></label>
        <span class="itext">3 AND 3</span>
    </div>

    <div id="paramount">paramount</div>
```

Comment: Great this is much better, from the looks of it you're trying to put query together for database. You want to aggregate everything from checkboxes, and on each select send what you have aggregated to backend to run some query. Can you tell me some desired results query if all are selected? i.e. what do you expect on backend?

Comment: @pegla Right now, i just want the opcaopreco and opcaopreco2 function to work, it doesnt matter the results. The struture must be preserved: x AND y OR w BETWEN a AND b. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing your counter to 0. It hits the `if counter == 0` and wont continue to the `else` where you have the `Test2` check

Comment: The counter gets to 1. For some reason it doesnt add upp anymore, but that should be enough to check for condition 2. I dont know why it doesnt.

Comment: Because you increment the counter after the else. What happens in the second click?

Comment: Try a console.log(inpActive) to see if it's getting that part right

Comment: Your counter problem is because you are using variable from local scope, it's always 0 so you will always get counter++ to be 1

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me show you much nicer solution for your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/11jm9k7a/10/

Sorry I just couldn't work with your code so I totally reworked your logic - might be that I missed something so let me know. This solution will work on unlimited different parameter groups, as long as you put on each checkbox element 2 different attributes, first one is query before which will hold string that goes before group in your first case:

```
query-before="BETWEEN"
```

and some string to identify group of query for your first case:

```
query-type="opcaopreco"
```

there's no need for any class/id's manipulations since this is generic solution.

**HTML:**

```
<br>
<br>
<label for="process">Final Query</label>
<input id="process" type="text" name="process" value='' placeholder='1 AND 11'>
<br>
<br>

<div id="op1l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op1" query-before="BETWEEN" query-type="opcaopreco" class="opcaopreco" value="201 AND 400" data-cpindex="1" data-cpactivo="">
  <label for="op1"></label>
  <span class="itext">€201 - €400</span>
</div>

<div id="op2l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op2" query-before="BETWEEN" query-type="opcaopreco" class="opcaopreco" value='401 AND 600' data-cpindex="2" data-cpactivo="">
  <label for="op2"></label>
  <span class="itext">€401 - €600</span>
</div>

<div id="op3l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op3" query-before="BETWEEN" query-type="opcaopreco" class="opcaopreco" value='601 AND 800' data-cpindex="3" data-cpactivo="">
  <label for="op3"></label>
  <span class="itext">€601 - €800</span>
</div>

<div id="op4l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op4" query-before="" query-type="opcaopreco2" class="opcaopreco2" value="1 AND 1" data-cpindex8="1" data-cpactivo8="">
  <label for="op4"></label>
  <span class="itext">1 AND 1</span>
</div>

<div id="op5l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op5" query-before="" query-type="opcaopreco2" class="opcaopreco2" value='2 AND 2' data-cpindex8="2" data-cpactivo8="">
  <label for="op5"></label>
  <span class="itext">2 AND 2</span>
</div>

<div id="op6l" class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="op6" query-before="" query-type="opcaopreco2" class="opcaopreco2" value='3 AND 3' data-cpindex8="3" data-cpactivo8="">
  <label for="op6"></label>
  <span class="itext">3 AND 3</span>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
  let query = {};

  // itterate through all input elements that have query-type attribute
  $('input[query-type]').each(function(value) {
    query[$(this).attr('query-type')] = {
      list: [],
      queryBefore: $(this).attr('query-before'),
    };
  });
  /* we first need to initialize arrays  so we can get in your case:
  query: {
    opcaopreco: {
        list: [],
        queryBefore: 'BETWEEN'
    },
    opcaopreco2: {
        list: [],
        queryBefore: ''
    },
  }
  */

  // after that attach on click even on all input elements that have query-type attribute
  $('input[query-type]').on('click', function(event) {
    // get query-type of $(this) - currently clicked element
    let typeOfQuery = $(this).attr('query-type');
    // check if this element is checked 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    /* if it is checked, push value to object and you will get
    query: {
      opcaopreco:  {
        list: ['201 AND 400'],
        queryBefore: 'BETWEEN'
      },
      opcaopreco2: {
        list: [],
        queryBefore: ''
      },
    }
    */
      query[typeOfQuery].list.push($(this).val());
    } else {
      // remove - splice element from array - check index of value and remove 1 element at that index
      query[typeOfQuery].list.splice(query[typeOfQuery].list.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
    }

    // we also need to sort array to get remove order which people clicked
    query[typeOfQuery].list.sort();
    // create temporary array that will hold query  
    let fullQuery = [];
    // loop through object keys
    Object.keys(query).forEach((value, index) => {
      // if there's something in array then do something otherwise don't do anything
      if (query[value].list.length > 0) {
        // first query join array with string ' AND ' to get ' AND ' between all values
        // after that split it to get all values in correct order
        let arrQuery = query[value].list.join(' AND ').split(' AND ');
        // use string literal to create a string which is basically first element and last element
        fullQuery.push(`${query[value].queryBefore} ${arrQuery[0]} AND ${arrQuery[arrQuery.length-1]}`);
        // this is same as using + sign on each element with spaces in between like below
        // fullQuery.push(query[value].queryBefore + ' '+ arrQuery[0] + ' AND '+ arrQuery[arrQuery.length-1]);
      }
    });

    // join all query types with OR keyword
    $('#process').val(fullQuery.join(' OR '));

  });

});
```

This solution is very extendable and will work in most cases it won't cover every possible scenario and parts of it may require more work depending on your exact parameters that you need or that before part and I just join everything with 'OR', but will work very good for similar type of thing.

Comment: This code that im presenting here is only a test part for a larger function that im making.  I need to use that counter to check for condition 1. Using inpActive for it wont do. Also, directly mentioning cpcounter9 in the Arra function wont do because i will need for "counter" to use diferent counters (cpcounter8, etc). i have once made a function that used a counter like that and it worked well. It didnt use parameters, but it should work like that, i suppose.

Comment: You need to be more clear in your requirements and give us a whole picture of your requirements if you wish to get good help. I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve with this, maybe even some real example would be more useful, so please update your question, more information is always welcome.

Comment: Im presenting the full code. Check the opening post.